# Почему не всегда добавляется комментарий с причиной закрытия вопроса?

Tags: поддержка, закрытие-вопросов

Когда под вопросом нажимают кнопку «закрыть» и выбирают причину закрытия, **часто** под вопросом автоматически добавляется комментарий (от имени предложившего закрытие) с текстом причины закрытия вопроса.

Но такой комментарий появляется далеко не всегда.

Пример (здесь я выбрал причину «не по теме — нет явного описания проблемы», и я, вроде, был первым, предложившим закрыть вопрос): [Обработка массива данных MySQL в PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/483223/178576)

Почему так происходит? Это «баг» или есть какая-то причина недобавления такого комментария?

Полистав [список закрытых вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20closed%3ayes), и почти не встретив авто-комментариев с причиной закрытия, прихожу к выводу, что, скорее, следует спрашивать: почему **иногда** появляются такие комментарии.

На всякий случай: примеры авто-комментариев, о которых речь в этом вопросе:

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/482754/#comment557504_482754
- [GET/POST запрос С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483075/#comment558215_483075)
- [Алгоритм прима на связном графе. где же ошибка?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/482352/#comment556349_482352)
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/482027/#comment555476_482027
- [Получение значения поиска Яндекс на своём сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443239/#comment467185_443239)

Comment: Читаю с мобильного (браузер, не приложение). Вижу: "Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе"

Comment: @NickVolynkin, видите комментарий? или, всё-таки, сообщение о закрытии вопроса (уже набралось достаточно голосов за закрытие с тех пор, как я написал свой вопрос на мете)?

Comment: Да, сообщение вижу на желтом фоне. Неверно вас понял. Именно комментарий появляется только про дубли.

Comment: *только про дубли* — явно нет: [пример1](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/482754/#comment557504_482754), [пример2](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483075/#comment558215_483075)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пользователи могут самостоятельно добавлять комментарии, копируя текст причины закрытия. Вероятно, авторы комментариев не захотели закрывать вопрос, вместо этого предпочли просто дать совет. Текст причин закрытия всегда под рукой, поэтому его легко скопировать и не надо думать, что написать.

Также копирование текста причины закрытия — удобное легковесное решение проблемы неправильно закрытого вопроса. Например, пользователь видит в очереди закрытия вопрос с тремя голосами на "too broad", эта причина заведомо победит, если вопрос будет решено закрыть, однако более уместна может быть другая причина (или верно сразу несколько). В этом случае уместно добавить комментарий с текстом более подходящей причины закрытия.

Автоматически комментарии добавляются только при закрытии дубликатов и пользовательских причинах закрытия.

Comment: *Автоматически комментарии добавляются только при закрытии дубликатов.* — нет. я привёл два примера в конце вопроса.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Обновил ответ.

Comment: вы явно отвечаете на какой-то другой вопрос. мой же вопрос состоит в том, почему авто-комментарии иногда добавляются, а иногда —нет.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Автор комментария сам написал комментарий, что непонятного? Вот, смотрите:

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: я не писал этот комментарий: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483075/#comment558215_483075 он был создан автоматически.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Это пользовательская причина закрытия. Вы таки ввели этот комментарий в поле для комментария при закрытии. Вы будете мне расказывать, что система ваши мысли прочитала, или такая причина закрытия у нас есть?

Comment: ещё раз: я не писал этот комментарий. он был создан автоматически: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483075/#comment558215_483075 . мне найти ещё примеров авто-комментариев, оставленных от моего имени (не с «пользовательской» причиной) или вас всё-таки удовлетворят примеры таких комментариев, авто-отправленных от имени других пользователей?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin У вас странное понимание "автоматически". Вы выбрали пункт "не по теме, потому что…" > "Другое (добавьте **комментарий, объясняющий причину закрытия**)" и почему-то считаете, что полученный комментарий "автоматический", а не "ручной". Если вы приведёте примеры со стандартными причинами закрытия — ОК, можно посмотреть. Но пока я не вижу массовости явления: https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/315109/comments-with-the-same-text Впрочем, фичу могли добавить на этой неделе, поэтому всё зависит от дат на комментариях.